# How can I add a new column meeting conditions of columns and a row of data

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rows

I have a data frame, call it df, that I want to add a new column "dsn" with two categorical groups "s" and "ns", based on conditions in columns 2 to 6 and row 1.

df:

```
df <- data.frame(refS_aa = c("", "N",   "L",    "T",    "T" ,"R",   "T",    "Q",    "T",    "N"),
             AAT = c("N",   38404, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0,38389),
             ACA    = c("T",    0,  0,  38387,  9,  7,  2,  351225, 0,  0),
             ACC    = c("T",    66, 0,  0,  38115,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0),
             ACG    = c("T",    0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0),
             ACT    = c("T",    0,  0,  0,  93, 0,  38304,  0,  38279,  0))

rownames(df) <- c("Used_aa",    "V1",   "V2",   "V3",   "V4",   "V5",   "V6",   "V7",   "V8",   "V9")
```

The df shows number of observations sharing the amino acids in column "refS_aa" and row 1 "Used_aa". My real data have over 7,000 observations.

The new column "dsn" should categorize the  numerical values in df into  "s" and "ns" factors based on conditions of row "Used_aa" and columns "2 to 6".

That is::

1. "s" should have Column 2 to 6  >0 & refS_aa = Used_aa
2. "ns" should have Column 2 to 6  >0 & refS_aa ≠ Used_aa

I have search solutions everywhere I could and tried different tricks including:

```
df$dsn[(df[2:6]) >0 ] & df[,1] == df[1,] <- "s"
df$dsn[(df[2:6]) >0 ] & df[,1] != df[1,] <- "ns"
```

But I have not succeeded.

I will appreciate any tricks!

Comment: Your columns are either character or factor or `> 0` is not correct

Comment: In the example, none of the rows have all columns with `"s" should have Column 2 to 6 >0`

Comment: Also, what is `d` object

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
df <- data.frame(refS_aa = c("", "N",   "L",    "T",    "T" ,"R",   "T",    "Q",    "T",    "N"),
                 AAT = c("N",   38404, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0,38389),
                 ACA    = c("T",    0,  0,  38387,  9,  7,  2,  351225, 0,  0),
                 ACC    = c("T",    66, 0,  0,  38115,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0),
                 ACG    = c("T",    0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0),
                 ACT    = c("T",    0,  0,  0,  93, 0,  38304,  0,  38279,  0))

rownames(df) <- c("Used_aa",    "V1",   "V2",   "V3",   "V4",   "V5",   "V6",   "V7",   "V8",   "V9")
```

The code:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(dsn = case_when(c(2:6) > 0 & refS_aa == "Used_aa" ~ "s",
                         c(2:6) > 0 & refS_aa != "Used_aa" ~"ns"))
```

gives this:
[image]

Comment: the `c(2:6)` may be the columns.  The condition in OP's post is unclear

Comment: One issue I have is regarding whether the OP meant any value > 0 or all.  OP didn't respond to my reply.   So, i think he is not interested in a solution

Comment: That is a good point. Lets see what the OP replies.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. TarJae's code is almost giving me what I want. It assigns "ns" where it should be  "s". Or we need a 3rd condition where both "s" and "ns" are satisfied, to to give another 3rd category

Comment: Yes, c(2:6) are columns

Comment: Expected new column: dns = c ("NA", "s,ns", "NA", "s", "s", "ns", "s,ns", "ns", "s", "s")